# Неправильно работают скрипты при подключении

Tags: wordpress

я впервые столкнулся с WP, так что прошу помощи. Есть js файлы, где главный - site.js

```js
import {Subscription} from "./subscription/subscription.js";
import {Annual} from "./subscription/annual.js";
import {Validation} from "./validation/validation.js";
import {Account} from "./account/account.js";

jQuery(function() {
    let subscription = new Subscription();
    subscription.executeAddons();
    subscription.showAddons();
    subscription.checkChangeSelectedAddons();
    subscription.checkChangeSelectedSubAddons();

    let v = new Validation();
    v.execute();

    let annual = new Annual();
    annual.setAnnual(subscription);
    subscription.checkChangeSlider(subscription);
    subscription.checkChangeStaffValue(subscription);

    let account = new Account();
    account.checkChange();

    v.submitForm(subscription, account);
});
```

Так же есть модули, которые вставляются в site.js. Пример модуля:

```js
import { Monthly } from "../subscription/monthly.js";
import { Annual } from "../subscription/annual.js";

export class Slider {
    isChecked = true;
    annual = new Annual();
    monthly = new Monthly();

    checkChange(subscription) {
        $('#s_toggle').on('change', () => {
            this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
            if (!this.isChecked) {
                $('.toggle-slider').css('background-color', 'white');
                $('.toggle-slider:before').css('transform', 'translateX(30px)');
                $('.toggle-label-left').css('color', 'black');
                $('.toggle-label-right').css('color', '#81d504');

                this.monthly.setMonthly(subscription);
                subscription.calculateAddons();

            } else {

                $('.toggle-slider').css('background-color', 'white');
                $('.toggle-slider:before').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
                $('.toggle-label-left').css('color', '#81d504');
                $('.toggle-label-right').css('color', 'black');

                this.annual.setAnnual(subscription);
                subscription.calculateAddons();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Простой html, css, js не на WP, то он работает хорошо, а вот на WP все будто ломается. css стили не все правильно становятся, js -  не работает слайдер и т.д. Возможно, что я неправильно подключил это все. function.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Functions and definitions.
 *
 * @link https://livecomposerplugin.com/themes/
 *
 * @package LC Blank
 */

// Delcare Header/Footer compatibility.
define( 'DS_LIVE_COMPOSER_HF', true );
define( 'DS_LIVE_COMPOSER_HF_AUTO', false );

// Content Width ( WP requires it and LC uses is to figure out the wrapper width ).
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 1180;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'lct_theme_setup' ) ) {

    /**
     * Basic theme setup.
     */
    function lct_theme_setup() {

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Enable Post Thumbnails ( Featured Image ).
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // Enable support for HTML5 markup.
        add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'search-form', 'comment-form' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'lct_theme_setup' );

/**
 * Load JS and CSS files.
 */
function lct_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lct-base-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/site.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'annual', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/subscription/annual.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'monthly', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/subscription/monthly.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'subscription', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/subscription/subscription.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'account', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/account/account.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'validation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/validation/validation.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'addon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/subscription/addon.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'subAddon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/subscription/subAddon.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lct_load_scripts' );

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 3 );
function add_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    // Если это не ваш скрипт, возвращаем исходный тег
    if ( ! in_array( $handle, array( 'site', 'slider', 'annual', 'monthly', 'subscription', 'account', 'validation', 'addon', 'subAddon' ), true ) ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    // Добавляем атрибут type="module" к вашим скриптам
    $tag = str_replace( '<script', '<script type="module"', $tag );

    return $tag;
}

function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_localize_script( 'site', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
if ( ! defined( 'DS_LIVE_COMPOSER_VER' ) ) {

    /**
     * Admin Notice
     */
    function lct_notification() {
    ?>
        <div class="error">
            <p><?php printf( __( '%sLive Composer%s plugin is %srequired%s and has to be active for this theme to function.', 'lc-blank' ), '<a target="_blank" href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/live-composer-page-builder/">', '</a>', '<strong>', '</strong>' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php }
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'lct_notification' );
}

/**
 * Proper <title> for header.php - Pass your seperator in header.php. Default: '|'
*/
function lct_title( $sep ) {
    the_title();
    echo ' ' . $sep . ' ';
    bloginfo( 'name ' );
}


function get_access_token(){
    // Параметры запроса
    $url = 'adsas';
    $method = 'POST';
    $data = array(
       
    );

    // Выполнение запроса
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method' => $method,
        'body' => $data
    ) );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) && wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) === 200 ) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $json = json_decode( $body );
        $access_token = $json->access_token;
        return $access_token;
        // Обработка успешного ответа
        // Действия, которые нужно выполнить с полученным $access_token
        // ...

        // Возвращаем ответ в формате JSON
        wp_send_json( array( 'access_token' => $access_token ) );
    } else {
        // Обработка ошибок
        $error_message = is_wp_error( $response ) ? $response->get_error_message() : 'Unknown error';
        wp_send_json_error( $error_message );
    }
}

function request1($url) {
    $access_token = get_access_token();
 

   // $headers = array(
    //   
     //   'X-com-subscriptions-organizationid' => '00000'
  //  );

    // Параметры запроса
  //  $args = array(
   //     'headers' => $headers
  //  );

    // Выполнение запроса
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);

    // Проверка наличия ошибок
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        wp_send_json_error($error_message);
    }

    // Обработка ответа
    $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    $startString = 'https://fasfsa.com/subscribe/';
    $endString = '&lt';
    $posStart = strpos($html, $startString);
    if ($posStart !== false) {
    $posEnd = strpos($html, $endString, $posStart);
    if ($posEnd !== false) {
        $substring = substr($html, $posStart, $posEnd - $posStart);
        return $substring;
    }
}
return $html;
}

function request2() {
    $access_token = get_access_token();
    // Отправка запроса 2 с использованием access token
    // ...
    // Обработка ответа запроса 2
}

function request3() {
    $access_token = get_access_token();
    // Отправка запроса 3 с использованием access token
    // ...
    // Обработка ответа запроса 3
}


function my_custom_action_callback() {
$request_type = isset($_GET['request_type']) ? $_GET['request_type'] : '';
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
    $response = '';
    // Выполнение различных запросов в зависимости от типа запроса
    if ($request_type === 'request1') {
      $response = request1($url);
    } elseif ($request_type === 'request2') {
        // Обработка запроса 2
    } elseif ($request_type === 'request3') {
        // Обработка запроса 3
    } else {
        // Обработка некорректного типа запроса
    }

    // Отправка ответа
    wp_send_json($response);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
```

Что не так с подключением?

Comment: Скорее всего, в файле header.php темы отсутствует вызов wp_head().

Comment: @KAGGDesign <?php wp_head(); ?> есть в header.php